# How to Use ffmpeg codes in iPHone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipod

I need to convert the video into png images. I did that using ffmepg. But I need to do that quickly. Now it's taking lots of time to convert a video into images. Now to reduce the conversion time. I search lot But I got "ffmpeg -i video.mpg image%d.jpg" these codings as solution. Please teach me to use these kind of codings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. shoot and save the video with AVCaptureSession + AVCaptureMovieFileOutput
2. use AVAssetReader to extract the individual frames from the video as BGRA CVImageBufferRefs
3. save as PNG: CVImageBufferRef -> UIImage -> UIImagePNGRepresentation

This should be faster than ffmpeg because step 2 is hardware accelerated and also has the benefit of allowing you to discard a cumbersome LPGLed 3rd party library.

Enjoy!

Comment: How to save the video as well as Images. Is their any possibility by using AVCaptureSession...

Comment: That's what step 1. does, the image creation uses the saved video. Edited to clarify.

Comment: @Rhythmic Fistman, hi please help on following link i m using step 2 method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816519/video-exporting-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

with ffmpeg you can split video frame by frame and can mix audio with video and also check [this](http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone)

Comment: I need to speed up the conversion... any idea?

Comment: means you need to increase bit rate ??

Comment: no fps rate.. Suppose If i need to convert a minute video means it will take atmost 40 sec. I need to reduce the conversion time....

Comment: Sorry I cont get my need from this link... Can u able to me xplain this.... I just need to shoot a video as well as sequence of images....